# Make a DISTINCT join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, distinct

I have a GridView bound to an LinqToSql-Datasource.

The Datasource represents 3 Tables which I select with a Join in Linq-Query.
The Tables are for persons, instititutions and memberships (mitgliedschaft).

A Person could have various Memberships belonging to different institutions.

My Query gets all Memberships but in the Table are shown only informations of the person or the institution, so there are duplicated rows in the rable.

I want only one person shown, although there are 3 memberships for example.
In SQL I would do it with a left join o something else, but I am LINQ-Newbie.

My Query is:

```
neonDataContext db = new neonDataContext();
                e.KeyExpression = "id";
                e.QueryableSource = from mitgliedschaft in db.mitgliedschaft

                                    join person in db.person on mitgliedschaft.person_id equals person.id
                                    join institution in db.institution on mitgliedschaft.verein_id equals institution.id

                                    select new
                                    {
                                        vorname = person.vorname,
                                        nachname = person.nachname,
                                        nameVerein = institution.name,
                                        vereinid = mitgliedschaft.verein_id,
                                        id = mitgliedschaft.id,
                                        verbandsnummer = person.verbandsMitgliedsNummer,
                                        strasse = person.strasse,
                                        plz = person.plz,
                                        ort = person.ort,
                                        geburtsdatum = person.geburtsdatum,
                                        geschlechtid = person.geschlechtid,
                                        statusid = mitgliedschaft.statusid,
                                        bezirk_id = mitgliedschaft.bezirk_id,
                                        kreis_id = mitgliedschaft.kreis_id,
                                        person_id = mitgliedschaft.person_id,
                                        deletedFlag = mitgliedschaft.deletedFlag
                                    };
```

Can someone tell me how to do distinct or left join with such a query, please?

Comment: Use Groupby.  The Group should give distinct results.

Comment: how do i use group by in this case?

Comment: Put parenthesis around the from : (from ......select new {......}).GroupBy(x => ....)

Comment: When I group in this way, the grid is telling me that some properties or fieldnames in the DataSource were not found

Comment: The properties for the group are the ones in your "select new"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning an enumeration of complex objects, the Distinct() operator by itself is inapplicable. Consider creating a class to represent the Person entity in your code and having it implement the IEquatable interface. This will allow the runtime to decide when two Person objects are in fact identical, by your own custom comparison logic.

See this article for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8

You can then use the Distinct() operator on the result set:

```
neonDataContext db = new neonDataContext();
                e.KeyExpression = "id";
                e.QueryableSource = (from mitgliedschaft in db.mitgliedschaft

                                    join person in db.person on mitgliedschaft.person_id equals person.id
                                    join institution in db.institution on mitgliedschaft.verein_id equals institution.id

                                    select new Person()
                                    {
                                        vorname = person.vorname,
                                        nachname = person.nachname,
                                        nameVerein = institution.name,
                                        vereinid = mitgliedschaft.verein_id,
                                        id = mitgliedschaft.id,
                                        verbandsnummer = person.verbandsMitgliedsNummer,
                                        strasse = person.strasse,
                                        plz = person.plz,
                                        ort = person.ort,
                                        geburtsdatum = person.geburtsdatum,
                                        geschlechtid = person.geschlechtid,
                                        statusid = mitgliedschaft.statusid,
                                        bezirk_id = mitgliedschaft.bezirk_id,
                                        kreis_id = mitgliedschaft.kreis_id,
                                        person_id = mitgliedschaft.person_id,
                                        deletedFlag = mitgliedschaft.deletedFlag
                                    }).Distinct();
```

Comment: can't make "select new Person()", because I need other table inside of select

Comment: You can initialize the new Person's fields just like in your own sample, the table aliases are accessible

Comment: do i have to create a class Person() for this. I got already a class named this way independent from the DataBase-Context

Comment: You need a class in order to implement the IEquatable interface. If the definition of the existing class makes it suitable for this case as well, you may consider just using that (after having it implement IEquatable)

Comment: the class only needs the attributes from inside the select-query? have implemented it, but now i got a "MissingPrimaryKeyException"

Comment: Does the exception occur during the evaluation of the linq query (following Distinct())? Or does it occur later when accessing e.QueryableSource in any way?

Comment: Message: A primary key field specified via the KeyFieldName property is not found in the underlying data source.     Is fired by the DataBind-Event of the GridView-Control

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinct by one field or multiple-field like person_id,you can add a extension function:

```
public static class  CustomDistinct{
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        {
            HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                {
                    yield return element;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it:

```
(from ... select...).DistinctBy(p => p.person_id); //one field

(from ... select...).DistinctBy(p => new{p.person_id,p.id}); //multiple-field
```

Comment: but how can I use it, if the "select new " is anonymous, like in my case?

Comment: you  can use it like:```(from ... select new {...,deletedFlag = mitgliedschaft.deletedFlag}).DistinctBy(p => p.person_id);```

Comment: when i do so, the whole query.part is underlined red. Saying that this anonymous type could not converted implicite in "System.Linq.IQueryable", because there is already explicite conversion

Comment: This is my test code,run successfully:```var list = (from com in comList
                        join emp in empList on com.ID equals emp.ID
                        select new
                        {
                            ComId = com.ComId,
                            Name = emp.FName,
                            Sex = emp.Sex,
                            ID = emp.ID,
                        }).DistinctBy(l =>l.ComId);```Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

Tried several Ways to achieve the Goal (implementing distinct in different ways and implenenting distinctBy-Extension).
The only Way that works in my case was, grouping and selecting first one:

```
neonDataContext db = new neonDataContext();
                e.KeyExpression = "id";
                e.QueryableSource = (from mitgliedschaft in db.mitgliedschaft

                                     join person in db.person on mitgliedschaft.person_id equals person.id
                                     join institution in db.institution on mitgliedschaft.verein_id equals institution.id

                                     select new
                                     {
                                         vorname = person.vorname,
                                         nachname = person.nachname,
                                         nameVerein = institution.name,
                                         vereinid = mitgliedschaft.verein_id,
                                         id = mitgliedschaft.id,
                                         verbandsMitgliedsNummer = person.verbandsMitgliedsNummer,
                                         strasse = person.strasse,
                                         plz = person.plz,
                                         ort = person.ort,
                                         geburtsdatum = person.geburtsdatum,
                                         geschlechtid = person.geschlechtid,
                                         statusid = mitgliedschaft.statusid,
                                         bezirk_id = mitgliedschaft.bezirk_id,
                                         kreis_id = mitgliedschaft.kreis_id,
                                         person_id = mitgliedschaft.person_id.Value,
                                         deletedFlag = mitgliedschaft.deletedFlag
                                     }).GroupBy(p => p.person_id).Select(p => p.First());
```

Comment: If you want to group by more than one : GroupBy(p => new { pid = p.person_id,  id = p.id})